# PHP stdClass vs "normal named" classes

Tags: php, object, anonymous-class

In the past, I used own classes for very many things. I know, that there are stdClasses provided by PHP itself. 
So I think, it would be more efficient to use them for little objects, because so I don't need to make hundreds of new classes ("helper classes").

Example:

```
public function getStatus() {
    $status = new Status("1", "success");
    return $status
}
```

class:

```
class Status
{
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function __construct($id, $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

(as you can see, the only reason I need classes like this, is to "return" data)

So when I code like this everytime, like I said, I have to create many classes for little usage.

Wouldn't it be better to use stdClass objects in cases like mine? What are the cons of this idea?

Comment: That is not a good idea. You should have separate and explicit classes for separate purposes. Rule of thumb: _chose explicit over implicit_. Otherwise the code gets really hard to read, harder to debug and your IDE cannot help with auto completion and the like.

Comment: why you don't use a parent class and use `__get` and `__set` methods?

Comment: @arkascha I understand that, but for bigger things like, i use normal objects (user objects, ...). It's all about very little objects with 2-3 variables and some get methods...

Answer (score 0):

Like for me better use helpers/classes like ArrayObject, Data, DataAccess etc.
Idead of this helpers/classes is fast storage and access data.

I never use stdClass objects. Even if i use functions like json_decode i put second argument true to get array of arrays instead of array of stdClasses.

Hope you understand me. Sorry for poor English :)

For example:

```
/**
 * @package   com_zoo
 * @author    YOOtheme http://www.yootheme.com
 * @copyright Copyright (C) YOOtheme GmbH
 * @license   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html GNU/GPL
 */

/**
 * Class for reading and writing in various formats
 *
 * @package Framework.Classes
 */
class AppData extends ArrayObject
{

    /**
     * Class constructor
     *
     * @param array $data The data array
     */
    public function __construct($data = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($data ? $data : array());
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the given key is present
     *
     * @param string $name The key to check
     *
     * @return boolean If the key was found
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function has($name)
    {
        return $this->offsetExists($name);
    }

    /**
     * Get a value from the data given its key
     *
     * @param string $key     The key used to fetch the data
     * @param mixed  $default The default value
     *
     * @return mixed The fetched value
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function get($key, $default = null)
    {

        if ($this->offsetExists($key)) {
            return $this->offsetGet($key);
        }

        return $default;
    }

    /**
     * Set a value in the data
     *
     * @param string $name  The key used to set the value
     * @param mixed  $value The value to set
     *
     * @return AppData The AppData object itself to allow chaining
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->offsetSet($name, $value);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove a value from the data
     *
     * @param string $name The key of the data to remove
     *
     * @return AppData The AppData object itself to allow chaining
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function remove($name)
    {
        $this->offsetUnset($name);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Magic method to allow for correct isset() calls
     *
     * @param string $name The key to search for
     *
     * @return boolean If the value was found
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function __isset($name)
    {
        return $this->offsetExists($name);
    }

    /**
     * Magic method to get values as object properties
     *
     * @param string $name The key of the data to fetch
     *
     * @return mixed The value for the given key
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->offsetGet($name);
    }

    /**
     * Magic method to set values through object properties
     *
     * @param string $name  The key of the data to set
     * @param mixed  $value The value to set
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->offsetSet($name, $value);
    }

    /**
     * Magic method to unset values using unset()
     *
     * @param string $name The key of the data to set
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function __unset($name)
    {
        $this->offsetUnset($name);
    }

    /**
     * Magic method to convert the data to a string
     *
     * Returns a serialized version of the data contained in
     * the data object using serialize()
     *
     * @return string A serialized version of the data
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return empty($this) ? '' : $this->_write($this->getArrayCopy());
    }

    /**
     * Utility Method to serialize the given data
     *
     * @param mixed $data The data to serialize
     *
     * @return string The serialized data
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected function _write($data)
    {
        return serialize($data);
    }

    /**
     * Find a key in the data recursively
     *
     * This method finds the given key, searching also in any array or
     * object that's nested under the current data object.
     *
     * Example:
     * <code>
     * $data->find('parentkey.subkey');
     * </code>
     *
     * @param string $key       The key to search for. Can be composed using $separator as the key/subkey separator
     * @param mixed  $default   The default value
     * @param string $separator The separator to use when searching for subkeys. Default is '.'
     *
     * @return mixed The searched value
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function find($key, $default = null, $separator = '.')
    {

        $key   = (string)$key;
        $value = $this->get($key);

        // check if key exists in array
        if ($value !== null) {
            return $value;
        }

        // explode search key and init search data
        $parts = explode($separator, $key);
        $data  = $this;

        foreach ($parts as $part) {

            // handle ArrayObject and Array
            if (($data instanceof ArrayObject || is_array($data)) && isset($data[$part])) {

                if ($data[$part] === null) {
                    return $default;
                }

                $data =& $data[$part];
                continue;
            }

            // handle object
            if (is_object($data) && isset($data->$part)) {

                if ($data->$part === null) {
                    return $default;
                }

                $data =& $data->$part;
                continue;
            }

            return $default;
        }

        // return existing value
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Find a value also in nested arrays/objects
     *
     * @param mixed $needle The value to search for
     *
     * @return string The key of that value
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function searchRecursive($needle)
    {
        $aIt = new RecursiveArrayIterator($this);
        $it  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($aIt);

        while ($it->valid()) {
            if ($it->current() == $needle) {
                return $aIt->key();
            }

            $it->next();
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Return flattened array copy. Keys are <b>NOT</b> preserved.
     *
     * @return array The flattened array copy
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function flattenRecursive()
    {
        $flat = array();
        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($this)) as $value) {
            $flat[] = $value;
        }

        return $flat;
    }
}



$array = array(
    'simple' => 'very simple array',
    'big'    => array(
        'bigbig' => array(
            'bigbigbig' => 'third level'
        )
    )
);
$data = new AppData($array);

echo $data->get('simple');                // very simple array
echo $data->find('big.bigbig.bigbigbig'); // third level
echo $data->get('not_found', 'novalue');  // novalue
```

Comment: Something like this - https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.php
But there are no recursive search :D When u working with big json data its realy economy the place.

Comment: could you give an example please?